# Ruby on Rails. Replace **Bold** with <b>Bold</b> with gsub()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `text_area/text_field` I want to give users option to add **bold** around some words. 
It would work like: This has a ** bold ** word inside.

I have used `.gsub('**', '<b>').html_safe` It almost works, but the problem is that the output is not exactly correct.

Expected Output: This has a **bold** word inside.

What I get: This has a **bold word inside.**

*html:*

```
<p>This has a <b>bold<b> word inside</b></b></p>
```

How can I make only the words that is surrounded with ** get `<b> </b>`

Comment: provide more details, `This has a **bold** word inside.` this is your text and you are use `gsub('**', '<b>')` so it will become `This has a <br>bold<br> word inside.` , so there is no closing `</b>`  and when it  comes actual `html` it becomes `This has a <b>bold<b> word inside</b></b>`

Comment: and one more question from where this kind of `string` you receive?

Comment: Or you can use pagedown editor. It's same editor that stackoverflow is using and its free and open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the match and pass it to the following block

```
string = "This has a **bold** word inside"

string.gsub(/\*\*(\w+)\*\*/) {"<b>#{$1}</b>"}

#=> "This has a <b>bold</b> word inside"
```

And it works for subsequent matches as well

```
string = "This has a **bold** word inside **bold**"

#=> "This has a <b>bold</b> word inside <b>bold</b>"
```

**EDIT**

If you want to capture spaces as well add `\s` to the regex

```
string = "This has a ** bold with spaces ** word inside **bold**"

string.gsub(/\*\*([\w\s]+)\*\*/) { "<b>#{$1}</b>" }

#=> "This has a <b> bold with spaces </b> word inside <b>bold</b>"
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak This work great, but only problem is if I have sentence inside the ** with spaces, it doesn't work, ex: ** this is a bold text **. Any fix for that?

Comment: Just replace the capture group and add space (/\*\*([\w\s]+)\*\*/)

Comment: @user6589814 Added a fix for it